# php regex failed, why?

Tags: php, regex

The value is `AbcDefg_123`.

Here is the regex:

```
function checkAlphNum($alphanumeric) {
   $return = false;
   if((preg_match('/^[\w. \/:_-]+$/', $alphanumeric))) {
      $return = true;
   } 
   return $return;
}
```

Should allow `a-zA-Z0-9.:_-/` and space in any order or format and does need all but at least one character.

EDIT: Sorry again, looks like var_dump() is my new best friend. I'm working with XML and it's passing the tag as well as the value.

@SilentGhost thnx for the tips.

Comment: Unrelated to question: `return preg_match(...);` will be clearer, if that's the entire function.

Comment: may be you could add semi-colon after the `$return`. It'd prevent syntax error.

Comment: @PiotrLegnica: `preg_match` return integer, though.

Comment: `(bool)preg_match` then. But it won't make much difference, unless caller checks both type and value.

Comment: it's so sad that not a single answer demonstrates that `_` (an underscore) is a part of `\w` :(

Comment: @SilentGhost I did know that the \w was a-zA-z0-9 but other than that what else does it cover? Am I being redundant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me too.

```
<?php

class RegexValidator
{
    public function IsAlphaNumeric($alphanumeric)
    {   
        return preg_match('/^[\w. \/:_-]+$/', $alphanumeric);
    }
}
?>
```

and this is how  I am testing it.

```
<?php
require_once('Classes/Utility.php');

$regexVal = new RegexValidator();


$list = array("abcd", "009aaa", "%%%%", "0000(", "aaaa7775aaa", "$$$$0099aaa", "kkdkdk", "aaaaa", "..0000", " ");

foreach($list as  $value)
{

    if($regexVal->IsAlphaNumeric($value))
    {
        echo  $value . " ------>passed";
        echo "<BR>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $value . "------>failed";
        echo "<br>";
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function checkAlphNum($alphanumeric) {
   $return = false;
   if((preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\w. \/:_-]+$/', $alphanumeric))) {
      $return = true;
   }
   return $return;
}

print checkAlphNum("AbcDefg_123");
```

Returns true.